# Can you trade Pokemon from Pokemon Emerald and Leaf Green with DS Lite?

Tags: nintendo-ds, game-boy-advance, pokemon-third-generation

I have a Gameboy Advance and a DS Lite at home. Is it possible to trade Pokemon from DS Lite instead of Gameboy Advance?

Answer (score 3):

No there is no way for any version of the DS to make use of the multiplayer functions of any GameBoy Advance cartridge, the system lacks the physical capacity to use either link cables or the GBA wireless adapter.